# Building log4cxx on visual 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++-2005, log4cxx

When I build the log4cxx on Visual 2005 according to instructions http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/building/vstudio.html, I am getting error below;

```
1>------ Build started: Project: apr, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>userinfo.c
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\platformsdk\include\rpcndr.h(145) :   error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\platformsdk\include\rpcndr.h(898) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
.
.
.
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\platformsdk\include\rpcndr.h(3119) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

When clicking the first error moves to code below

```
/****************************************************************************
 *  Other MIDL base types / predefined types:
 ****************************************************************************/

typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef ::byte cs_byte;   // error indicates here
```

Is there any comment??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having a problem building log4cxx.0.10.0 in windows (I don't remember if it was the exactly the same one you have) and I followed this [steps](http://www.elpauer.org/?p=250).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks very much like there is a #define or two missing. Did you successfully open and convert the project files as described in the build instructions?